# Add column with row values based on a category to R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, transpose

so I have a dataframe of the following structure, let's call this one df0:

| year | category | a | b | c | d |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1989 | 1 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.43 | 321 |
| 1989 | 1 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.43 | 321 |
| 1989 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 174 |
| 1989 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 174 |
| 1989 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 174 |
| 1989 | 3 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 3.0 | 224 |
| 1990 | 1 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 3.0 | 93 |
| 1990 | 1 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 3.0 | 93 |
| 1990 | 2 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 4.0 | 293 |
| 1990 | 3 | 0.9 | 0.6 | 2.0 | 13 |

What I need to turn this into is the following. Basically, I want to add for each year a column with the a c value for each category. Like this:

| year | category | a | b | c | d | c1 | c2 | c3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1989 | 1 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.43 | 321 | 0.43 | 0.5 | 3.0 |
| 1989 | 1 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 0.43 | 321 | 0.43 | 0.5 | 3.0 |
| 1989 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 174 | 0.43 | 0.5 | 3.0 |
| 1989 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 174 | 0.43 | 0.5 | 3.0 |
| 1989 | 2 | 0.2 | 0.4 | 0.5 | 174 | 0.43 | 0.5 | 3.0 |
| 1989 | 3 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 3.0 | 224 | 0.43 | 0.5 | 3.0 |
| 1990 | 1 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 3.0 | 93 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 |
| 1990 | 1 | 0.6 | 0.2 | 3.0 | 93 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 |
| 1990 | 2 | 0.3 | 0.7 | 4.0 | 293 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 |
| 1990 | 3 | 0.9 | 0.6 | 2.0 | 13 | 3.0 | 4.0 | 2.0 |

I cannot figure out how to compute this. My first Idea would be to create sub dataframes for each year and then create a vector of each c value from this, but this seems very tedious and I cannot get it to work.

Does anyone have input or a solution on this?

KR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using tidyr and dplyr, pivot then join:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

cvals <- df0 %>%
  distinct(year, category, c) %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = category,
    names_prefix = "c",
    values_from = c
  )

left_join(df0, cvals, join_by(year))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 9
    year category     a     b     c     d    c1    c2    c3
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1989        1   0.3   0.7  0.43   321  0.43   0.5     3
 2  1989        1   0.3   0.7  0.43   321  0.43   0.5     3
 3  1989        2   0.2   0.4  0.5    174  0.43   0.5     3
 4  1989        2   0.2   0.4  0.5    174  0.43   0.5     3
 5  1989        2   0.2   0.4  0.5    174  0.43   0.5     3
 6  1989        3   0.6   0.2  3      224  0.43   0.5     3
 7  1990        1   0.6   0.2  3       93  3      4       2
 8  1990        1   0.6   0.2  3       93  3      4       2
 9  1990        2   0.3   0.7  4      293  3      4       2
10  1990        3   0.9   0.6  2       13  3      4       2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to gather all `unique` values in each `year` and reshape the data in wide format using `pivot_wider`. We can join this reshaped data with original data by `year` to get back expected data frame as output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  reframe(unique_c = unique(c), .by = year) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), .by = year) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = row, names_prefix = "c", values_from = unique_c) %>%
  left_join(df, by = join_by(year)) %>%
  # Optional, only to get data in same order as expected output
  relocate(year, category, a:d)

#   year category     a     b     c     d    c1    c2    c3
#   <int>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  1989        1   0.3   0.7  0.43   321  0.43   0.5     3
# 2  1989        1   0.3   0.7  0.43   321  0.43   0.5     3
# 3  1989        2   0.2   0.4  0.5    174  0.43   0.5     3
# 4  1989        2   0.2   0.4  0.5    174  0.43   0.5     3
# 5  1989        2   0.2   0.4  0.5    174  0.43   0.5     3
# 6  1989        3   0.6   0.2  3      224  0.43   0.5     3
# 7  1990        1   0.6   0.2  3       93  3      4       2
# 8  1990        1   0.6   0.2  3       93  3      4       2
# 9  1990        2   0.3   0.7  4      293  3      4       2
#10  1990        3   0.9   0.6  2       13  3      4       2
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(year = c(1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 
1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L), category = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), a = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6, 
0.6, 0.3, 0.9), b = c(0.7, 0.7, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.7, 0.6), c = c(0.43, 0.43, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2), d = c(321L, 
321L, 174L, 174L, 174L, 224L, 93L, 93L, 293L, 13L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: This works perfectly apart from one issue: If there are jumps in the category value, say, there is a category 5, no 6, but a 7, then it only adds columns for 1 to including 6, not the rest, say if there are still categories 7-9. Any idea on how to fix this? Really appreciate your support!

Comment: In that case, solution from @zephryl would be more suitable I guess.